# Как закрывать аккордеон, при выборе другого элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот в чём заключается вопрос. У меня есть некий аккордеон и мне надо, чтоб каждый элемент закрывался при нажатии на другой элемент. Пока есть только такой код. Буду благодарен помощи.

```
$('.shield').click(function (){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.accord_bg_desc_mob_shield').toggleClass('active');
});
 $('.currency').click(function (){
  $(this).toggleClass('activey');
  $('.accord_bg_desc_mob_currency').toggleClass('active');
});
 $('.target').click(function (){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.accord_bg_desc_mob_target').toggleClass('active');
});
 $('.clock').click(function (){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.accord_bg_desc_mob_clock').toggleClass('active');
});
 $('.like').click(function (){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.accord_bg_desc_mob_like').toggleClass('active');
});
 $('.planet').click(function (){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.accord_bg_desc_mob_planet').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменяй местами переключения класса, и должно работать.

```
$('.shield').click(function (){
    $('.accord_bg_desc_mob_shield').toggleClass('active'); //Сначала переключаем класс всем объектам по классу
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); //Затем тому, на который кликнули
});
```

Вообще, хорошо бы эти все блоки обернуть в одну функцию и вызывать.
Например:

```
//Создать функцию переключатель классов
function accordeonAction (items_class, item) {
    $(items_class).toggleClass('active');
    $(item).toggleClass('active');
}
// И вызывать когда необходимо
$('.planet').click(function (){ //Тут, вместо click, может быть любое необходимое событие
    accordeonAction ('.accord_bg_desc_mob_planet', $(this));
});
```

Сократит общий код, добавит функциональности и облегчит его читаемость в будущем

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо за функцию, сократила много кода, но вы немного не поняли(скорее я плохо объяснил), $(this).toggleClass('active'); добавляет стили для кнопки, а $('.accord_bg_desc_mob_shield').toggleClass('active'); открывает нужный нам блок.

Comment: А почему не сделать и добавление стилей и открытие блока при клике, в одном месте?
`$(this).toggleClass('active');` - здесь.
При нажатии на нужный блок, задавать ему стили и для открытия и дополнительные.

Comment: https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/8/21/a8e0c1f072fa302b765322c31a40812a-full.png , не обычный аккордеон из-за чего пришлось, сделать кнопки и блоки отдельно.

Comment: Не знаю, какая там разметка, но нужно перед сменой класса для открытия элемента, сменить класс всем остальным элементам, которые не имеют этого класса.
Допустим:
`$('.some-class').toggleClass('active');
$('.some-class.accord_bg_desc_mob_planet').toggleClass('active');`
Это закроет все элементы аккордеона с классом `.some-class`, и откроет необходимый.

Comment: toggleClass? Он же просто добавляет?

Comment: @VashkaStream
`toggleClass()` - переключает состояние указанного класса. Т.е. ,если на элемент установлен класс `.active`, эта функция его удалит, и наоборот, если на элементе такого класса нет, функция его добавит.

Comment: Но при этом оно откроет и не открытые, так как это переключатель

Comment: @VashkaStream
Если указать только нужный тебе элемент - остальные элементы эта функция не затронет.

Чтобы было надежней, можешь через  `removeClass(element)` - удалять класс с элемента(ов), а через `addClass(element)` добавлять класс элементу(ам).

Comment: Я немного запутался. Можете приложить полный код, который останется только присоединить?

Comment: @VashkaStream у меня нет верстки, чтобы знать, как ты хочешь это использовать.